# Can I clone an IQueryable to run on a DbSet for another DbContext?

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Suppose I have built up, through some conditional logic over many steps, an `IQueryable<T>` instance we'll call `query`.

I want to get a count of total records and a page of data, so I want to call `query.CountAsync()` and `query.Skip(0).Take(10).ToListAsync()`.  I cannot call these in succession, because a race condition occurs where they both try to run a query on the same `DbContext` at the same time. This is not allowed:

> "A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

I do not want to 'await' the first before even starting the second. I want to fire off both queries as soon as possible. The only way to do this is to run them from separate DbContexts. It seems ridiculous that I might have to build the entire query (or 2, or 3) side-by-side starting with different instances of `DbSet`. Is there any way to clone or alter an `IQueryable<T>` (not necessarily that interface, but it's underlying implementation) such that I can have one copy that runs on `DbContext` "A", and another that will run on `DbContext` "B", so that both queries can be executing simultaneously? I'm just trying to avoid recomposing the query X times from scratch just to run it on X contexts.

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard way of doing that. The problem is that EF6 query expression trees contain constant nodes holding `ObjectQuery` instances which are bound to the `DbContext` (actually the underlying `ObjectContext`) used when creating the query. Also there is a runtime check before executing the query if there are such expressions bound to a different context than the one executing the query.

The only idea that comes in my mind is to process the query expression tree with `ExpressionVisitor` and replace these `ObjectQuery` instances with new ones bound to the new context.

Here is a possible implementation of the aforementioned idea:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace System.Data.Entity
{
    public static class DbQueryExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> BindTo<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, DbContext target)
        {
            var binder = new DbContextBinder(target);
            var expression = binder.Visit(source.Expression);
            var provider = binder.TargetProvider;
            return provider != null ? provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression) : source;
        }

        class DbContextBinder : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            ObjectContext targetObjectContext;
            public IQueryProvider TargetProvider { get; private set; }
            public DbContextBinder(DbContext target)
            {
                targetObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)target).ObjectContext;
            }
            protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
            {
                if (node.Value is ObjectQuery objectQuery && objectQuery.Context != targetObjectContext)
                    return Expression.Constant(CreateObjectQuery((dynamic)objectQuery));
                return base.VisitConstant(node);
            }
            ObjectQuery<T> CreateObjectQuery<T>(ObjectQuery<T> source)
            {
                var parameters = source.Parameters
                    .Select(p => new ObjectParameter(p.Name, p.ParameterType) { Value = p.Value })
                    .ToArray();
                var query = targetObjectContext.CreateQuery<T>(source.CommandText, parameters);
                query.MergeOption = source.MergeOption;
                query.Streaming = source.Streaming;
                query.EnablePlanCaching = source.EnablePlanCaching;
                if (TargetProvider == null)
                    TargetProvider = ((IQueryable)query).Provider;
                return query;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One difference with the standard EF6 LINQ queries is that this produces `ObjectQuery<T>` rather than `DbQuery<T>`, although except that `ToString()` does not return the generated SQL, I haven't noticed any difference in the further query building / execution. It seems to work, but use it with care and on your own risk.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a function to build up your query, taking DbContext as a parameter.

```
 public IQueryable<T> MyQuery(DbContext<T> db)
 {
     return db.Table
              .Where(p => p.reallycomplex)
              ....
              ...
              .OrderBy(p => p.manythings);
 }
```

I've done this many times and it works well. 
Now it's easy to make queries with two different contexts:

```
IQueryable<T> q1 = MyQuery(dbContext1);
IQueryable<T> q2 = MyQuery(dbContext2);
```

If your concern was the execution time taken to build the IQueryable objects, then my only suggestion is don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

So you have an `IQueryable<T>` that will be performed on DbContext A as soon as the query is executed and you want the same query to run on DbContext B when the query is executed.

For this you'll have to understand the difference between an `IEnumerable<T>` and an `IQueryable<T>`.

An `IEnumerable<T>` holds all code to enumerate over the elements that the enumerable represents. The enumeration starts when `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` are called. This can be done explicitly. However it is usually done implicitly by functions like `foreach`, `ToList`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc.

An `IQueryable` does not hold the code to enumerate, it holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Provider knows who will execute the query, and it knows how to translate the `Expression` into the language that is understood by the query executioner.

Due to this separation, it is possible to let the same Expression be executed by different data sources. They don't even have to be of the same type: one data source can be a database management system that understands SQL, the other one could be a comma separated file.

As long as you concatenate Linq statements that return an IQueryable, the query is not executed, only the Expression is changed.

As soon as enumeration starts, either by calling GetEnumerator / MoveNext, or by using foreach or one of the LINQ functions that do not return an IQueryable, the Provider will translate the Expression into the language the the data source understands and communicates with the data source to execute the query. The result of the query is an IEnumerable, which can be enumerated as if all data was in local code.

Some Providers are smart and use some buffering, so that not all data is transferred to local memory, but only part of the data. New data is queried when needed. So if you do a foreach in a database with a zillion elements, only the first few (thousands) elements are queried. More data is queried if your foreach runs out of fetched data.

So you already have one `IQueryable<T>`, therefore you have an `Expression` a `Provider` and an ElementType. You want the same `Expression / ElementType to be executed by a different`Provider`. You even want to change the`Expression` slightly before you execute it.

Therefore you need to be able to create an object that implements `IQueryable<T>` and you want to be able to set the `Expression`, `ElementType` and a `Provider`

```
class MyQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
     public type ElementType {get; set;}
     public Expression Expression {get; set;}
     public Provider Provider {get; set;}
} 

IQueryable<T> queryOnDbContextA= dbCotextA ...
IQueryable<T> setInDbContextB = dbContextB.Set<T>();

IQueryable<T> queryOnDbContextB = new MyQueryable<T>()
{
     ElementType = queryOnDbContextA.ElementType,
     Expression = queryOnDbContextB.Expression,
     Provider = setInDbContextB.Provider,
}
```

If desired you can adjust the query on the other context before executing it:

```
var getPageOnContextB = queryOnDbContextB
    .Skip(...)
    .Take(...);
```

Both queries are still not executed yet. Execute them:

```
var countA = await queryOnContextA.CountAsync();
var fetchedPageContextB = await getPageOnContextB.ToListAsync();
```